# Redirect is not working with JavaScript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My issue is kind of simple, but is taking me some time to solve.

The problem is: I have a HTML form with 2 buttons, see the code below:

```
    $html1 = "<div class='pai-forms'>
            <form method='post'>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Dados do Salão:</legend>
                    <div>";

$html2 =            "</div>
                    <div class='dividersolid'></div>
                    <button name='action' class='btn btn-skin btn-primary btn-cadastro' type='submit' value='atualizar' onclick='confirmationUpdate()'>Atualizar</button>
                    <button name='action' class='btn btn-skin btn-primary btn-cadastro' type='submit' value='deletar' onclick='confirmationDelete()'>Deletar</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>";
```

Note that my buttons execute a jquery function when click.
Here is my jQuery functions:

```
    function confirmationDelete() {
    var answer = confirm("Você tem certeza que deseja deletar este salão?");
    if (answer) {
        <?php wsDeleteSalon($id, $token); header("location:list_salons.php");?>
        window.location = "list_salons.php";
        window.location.replace("list_salons.php");
        window.location.href = "list_salons.php";
        alert("Salão deletado com sucesso.");
    }
    else {
        alert("Salão não deletado.");
    }
}
function confirmationUpdate() {
    var answer = confirm("Você tem certeza que deseja atualizar este salão?");
    if (answer) {
        <?php wsUpdateSalon($id, $name, $email, $cep, $numero, $complemento, $rua, $logo, $lat, $lng, $token); header("location:list_salons.php");?>
        window.location = "list_salons.php";
        window.location.replace("list_salons.php");
        window.location.href = "list_salons.php";
        alert("Salão atualizado com sucesso.");
    }
    else {
        alert("Salão não atualizado.");
    }
}
```

Everything is working great but when I try to redirect the page with php or javascript, it's not redirecting to any page.

What am I missing? Does anyone have a tip?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many, many problems with this code, mostly the lack of quotes and what appears to be PHP _inside_ the jQuery. Edit the question with more refined code.

Comment: Have you checked for errors yourself? For example php error reporting and/or the browser console?

Comment: @yak613 Why I can't use PHP inside jQuery? and the quotes is the only way I found to work with it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix PHP and JavaScript like that. JavaScript runs on the browser, PHP runs on the server. What I think is happening is that your JavaScript is  breaking when it hits the PHP tag, so not executing your redirect.

The solution is to remove the PHP and change the redirect to a PHP script that executes your delete routine, then performs your list function.

Answer (score 1):

*As I can't comment yet.*

Try using `window.location` instead of `window.location.href`

**EDIT:** Try this instead of all types of redirect *checking for errors.*

```
if (answer) {
    alert("Error check [1]");
    window.location = "list_salons.php";
    alert("Error check [2]");
    alert("Salão deletado com sucesso.");
} else {
    alert("Salão não deletado.");
}
```

And, where is your PHP code?

Comment: take a look at my code, i'm already trying to use window.location

Comment: I've seen it, but use the `alert()` function to see where your code stops executing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my similar syntax for that operation that works good. I just have a folder and my php spans a bit farther down but same thing.

```
      <?php
      session_start():
      if(empty($_session['user']))
      {
       header('Location: login/login.php');
       exit;
      }
```